# Fix angle between two bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

Is there any way to keep the angle between two bones fixed?

Here is what I am trying to do. I got an armature consisting of three bones. I IK constrained the tail bone to a dummy and when I move the parent bone, the armature should move in a way that the angle between the middle bone and the tail is fixed. I have tried all kinds of tricky stuff, but couldn't get it work.

Here is what I mean (sorry for the annoying logo!).

Basically, I need the angle between the black bone and yellow bone preserved. It is possible whenever the parent bone (blue) and the IK bone (yellow) rotate "more" so to speak. I mean, it's possible mechanically.

[image: Animation]

Comment: can you use one single bone for the middle and the tail? From the looks of the object, it really is only one piece.

Comment: Maybe, I am using the terminology wrong, but from my perspective a bone is linear piece of an armature. There are three bones in my situation.

Comment: If you **never** want that portion of the object to bend, you can treat the whole part as one bone ... regardless of it's shape. So take out the bone you don't need and simplify the rig.

Comment: @hawkenfox Ok. **I need** this configuration of the bones. I bind an object to the IK bone and I need it move in the said manner.

Comment: @ValerySaharov You only *need* this configuration if those 2 bones (black and yellow) will ever move/rotate/scale against each other. Do they? Do you need the joint in there? If yes I'll write a solution for you but if no just use single bone there.

Comment: @Jerryno I need the angle between the black and yellow bone to be fixed as if the black and yellow bones were a rigid construction. The tail of the yellow bone is connected to a hinge. There should another hinge between the blue and black bones. When I move the blue bone horizontally, the part consisting of the black and yellow bones as a whole needs to rotate around the hinge marked by a square on the picture.

Comment: @ValerySaharov So if black and yellow bones are a rigid construction then use **only 1 bone for them**. Parent both your rigid pieces (that you currently represent with black and yellow) to this bone. You don't need 2 bones there.

Comment: @Jerryno Imagine if this construction is a planar mechanism with two hinges -- one at the empy cube, and another -- at the connection of the blue bone to the black one; and a horizontal slider. If you make the black and yellow bones to one, you don't get the right rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to substitute both bones with just one:

Select the Yellow bone and under *Inverse Kinematics* enable all the locks:

[image]

Now it's a rigid piece:

[image]

Comment: Exactly! For some reason, I've tried the same with the black bone and it didn't work. Seems to be not so intuitive as to why exactly the yellow bone's rotation needs to be locked.

Answer (score 1):

Move the IK object one parent down the line.

[image]

Here is the blend file.

[image]

> In IK rigging terms, it's the IK object that animator work with. The
>   other bones "reacts" to the movement of the IK object. You will often
>   find that when animator work on an IK rig, they hide all the bones
>   that aren't IK object ... simple because they don't directly interact/transform them.

Comment: It would be what I need, if **arm.lower**'s tail were fixed as in my picture.

Comment: I need it to do what it does on my picture when I move the blue bone horizontally, not the IK object.

Comment: The moved IK target has different rotation origin and the constraint solution does not affect IK rotations - only Pose rotations - so that does not work at all, the constraint is redundant there.

Comment: I agree with your remark. I just omitted another IK that should have been at the blue bone's head